# Switching storyboards at runtime based on device

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, storyboard

what code needs to be implemented in order to switch storyboards at runtime based on device? I'm designing in landscape but am having difficulty using constraints (having major layout issues displaying on 3.5 screen as have developed/designed whole app in 4.0 window), have seen the next logical move is to setup a second main window (for 3.5) and have it set that when the user opens the app then the correct screen will load..

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Ask about the problems you have with constraints.

Comment: Please don't create duplicates of your own questions. I'm voting to close this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23303790/xcode-code-to-implement-that-directs-the-correct-xib-at-runtime

Answer (score 0):

Use auto layouts? Stanford university lecture explains the basics, scroll to 25:00 in the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1sc7NI6-wo